# Graphics Context misaligned on first paint

Tags: java, swing, affinetransform

I've been working up an answer for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506118/using-slider-to-rotate-object-in-java) and came across a bizare issue that I've not seen before...

Basically, the program uses a `AffineTransform` to provide translation, scaling and rotating of a `Graphics` element, simple enough stuff, done a thousand times before

The problem is, when the screen first appears, the output is not where it should be, but once I touch one of the controls (adjust one of the slides) it jumps to the right spot.

[image: Slider][image: Slider]

Based on the screen shots, the `Graphics` content seems to be misplaced by the amount of the other controls.

If I remove the controls from the GUI, it appears in the right spot (in the center).  If I resize the window, it doesn't fix the issue, it only fixes when one of the sliders triggers `repaint` on the `DrawPane`...

I've added diagnostics to the output and the all the values are the same - that is, they print the same values when the program first starts and when I adjust all slider values to their initial values.

If I remove the `setRotation` and `setScale` calls from the `AffineTransform`, it doesn't fix it.  If I remove the `setTranslation`, the square isn't initially painted until the panel is updated (it's painted off screen)

If I use `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics)g;` instead of `g.create()`, same result (and yes, I reset the transform before the `paintComponent` method exited ;))

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Parker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Parker();
    }

    public Parker() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ControlPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ControlPane extends JPanel {

        private JSlider slider; //declare slider
        private DrawPane myPanel; 
        public ControlPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            myPanel = new DrawPane();
            myPanel.setBackground(Color.cyan); //change background color

            slider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, 0, 400, 100);// restrains the slider from scaling square to 0-300 pixels
            slider.setMajorTickSpacing(20); //will set tick marks every 10 pixels
            slider.setPaintTicks(true); //this actually paints the ticks on the screen

            slider.addChangeListener(
                    new ChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                            myPanel.setScale(slider.getValue()); //Wherever you set the slider, it will pass that value and that will paint on the screen
                        }
                    }
            );

            JSlider rotate = new JSlider(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, 0, 720, 0);
            rotate.setMajorTickSpacing(20); //will set tick marks every 10 pixels
            rotate.setPaintTicks(true); //this actually paints the ticks on the screen

            rotate.addChangeListener(
                    new ChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                            JSlider slider = (JSlider) e.getSource();
                            myPanel.setAngle(slider.getValue()); 
                        }
                    }
            );
            add(slider, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(rotate, BorderLayout.EAST);

            add(myPanel);

            slider.setValue(0);
            slider.setValue(100);
            rotate.setValue(0);

        }

    }

    public class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        private double scale = 1;
        private double angle = 0;

        private final int rectWidth = 20;
        private final int rectHeight = 20;


        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)//paints obj on the screen
        {
            super.paintComponent(g); //prepares graphic object for drawing

            int originX = getWidth() / 2; 
            int originY = getHeight() / 2;

            int xOffset = -(rectWidth / 2);
            int yOffset = -(rectHeight / 2);

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.translate(originX, originY);
            g2d.setTransform(at);
            g2d.scale(scale, scale);
            g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), 0, 0);
            g2d.fillRect(xOffset, yOffset, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            g2d.dispose();

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(originX + xOffset, originY + yOffset, rectWidth, rectWidth);
        }

        public void setAngle(double angle) {
            this.angle = angle;
            repaint();
        }

        public void setScale(int scale) {
            // Scaling is normalized so that 1 = 100%
            this.scale = (scale / 100d);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Basically, it appears that the `Graphics` context, for some reason is not been translated properly when it is first painted and I have no idea why...

ps- Test on Java 6 and Java 7 under Windows 7
pps- I've also tried setting the initial scale and rotation to other values before the screen was visible, same result

**System Properties**

```
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
file.encoding=UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
file.separator=\
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.class.path=C:\DevWork\personal\java\projects\wip\SystemProperties\build\classes
java.class.version=51.0
java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\endorsed
java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_51-b13
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=1.7
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=1.7
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version=24.51-b03
os.arch=amd64
os.name=Windows 7
os.version=6.1
path.separator=;
sun.arch.data.model=64
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
sun.desktop=windows
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command=systemproperties.SystemProperties
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1
user.country=AU
user.dir=C:\DevWork\personal\java\projects\wip\SystemProperties
user.home=C:\Users\shane
user.language=en
user.name=shane
user.script=
user.timezone=
user.variant=
```

**Updated**

If I use...

```
g2d.translate(originX, originY);
g2d.scale(scale, scale);
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), 0, 0);
```

Instead of the `AffineTransform`, it works fine. I've noted that it doesn't matter how I use the `AffineTransform` (translation only, rotation only, scale only) I seem to get the same results

**Updated with example image**

Example showing resizing frame...

[image: ZoomSpinResizeFrame]

nb The last position shift of the rectangle is a result of the `MouseListener` mentioned below

However, if I add a `MosueListener` to the `DrawPane` (either direclty within the class or externally via the `myPanel` instance) and call `repaint` on `mouseClicked`, it re-aligns correctly :P

**Updated**

If I translate a `Shape`, using the following

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.translate(originX, originY);
at.scale(scale, scale);
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), 0, 0);
g2d.setTransform(at);

Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(xOffset, yOffset, rectWidth, rectHeight);
Shape shape = at.createTransformedShape(rect);

System.out.println(rect.getBounds());
System.out.println(shape.getBounds());
```

The resulting output is in align with expectations, but the (graphics) output is still wrong...

Comment: Cannot reproduce in 1.7.0_25 on Windows.  Can you add a dump of some of the system properties in the main?

Comment: Java 1.7.0_51 and Java 1.6.0_45

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've added most of the `System.properties`

Comment: Riiight.. but I meant.. `frame.setVisible(true); ..` -> `frame.setVisible(true); System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version")); ..` or similar.  This is intended to get test results from others as to the circumstances when this (apparently JRE specific) bug happens.

Comment: Oh wait a second..  I just accidentally widened the frame a little and the black square leaped to the left.  It seems 1.7.0_25 is affected, just in a slightly different way..

Comment: Replicated with Java 8 as well...

Comment: Could be a "Windows" "driver" issues, Windows did just update :P

Comment: ..I also got a Windows update in the last couple of days.

Comment: If I don't use `AffineTransform` and use `Graphics#translate/scale/rotate` it works :P

Comment: Please edit that comment about using `AffineTransform` into the question.  The code itself would also benefit from a check box that would allow us to try out both methods..

Comment: @AndrewThompson The problem with a check box is it could cause a `repaint` which would "fix" the problem as it seems to be only on startup :P

Comment: Have you tried dragging the frame a little wider?  Strange things seem to happen then as well (here that is the *only* time strange things happen, not at start up).

Comment: Yeah, doesn't affect it all, even though `paintComponent` is called, the two rectangles stay misaligned...

Comment: Actually, I was more referring to (after start-up) shifting the frame width to *produce* a strange behavior.  You are not seeing that?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Programmatically or manually?  I've added an animated GIF to demonstrate the manual resizing. Add a `MouseListener` to the `DrawPanel` and called `repaint` on `MouseClicked` and that realigned the output :P

Comment: @AndrewThompson Also used `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to change the frame size and a Swing `Timer`, same result

Comment: I meant manually, and your animated GIF tells me you are not seeing the same as I am, though I altered the sliders *before* adjusting the frame size.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I can concur, altering the slider positions and the resizing mis-aligns the rectangles again...using the sliders again then re-aligns them :P

Comment: You have checked the bug DB on this?  If it is due to the latest Windows update, any bug probably would not have been cleared for public viewing yet (or have been rejected, if the answer is 'talk to MS').  It would be nice to get a 'works fine' from one of our colleagues running *nix or OS X..

Comment: Same problem on Mac OS X, Java 7.

Comment: Why would this question ever attract a downvote?  Seriously?

Comment: It's really interesting when someone down votes without leaving a note as to why, cause I'd be really interested in known what's wrong with this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `AffineTransform` associated with the graphics context passed to `paintComponent()` is not *always* the identity transform. For reasons that aren't clear, the `m12` entry has the value `38.0` initially and after resizing the enclosing frame. Trivially, one can modify the copy supplied by `g.create()`.

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
AffineTransform at = g2d.getTransform();
at.translate(originX, originY);
g2d.setTransform(at);
g2d.scale(scale, scale);
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), 0, 0);
g2d.fillRect(xOffset, yOffset, rectWidth, rectHeight);
g2d.dispose();
```

Addendum: As @MadProgrammer observes, "If I remove the controls from the GUI, it appears … in the center." Indeed, the observed horizontal offset is precisely the preferred width of the `slider` in `BorderLayout.WEST`. I suspect that the origin is adjusted after a resize to meet the [`Component#paintAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paintAll%28java.awt.Graphics%29) contract more easily: "The origin of the graphics context, its `(0, 0)` coordinate point, is the top-left corner of this component."

Comment: I'd welcome a better answer, but I suspect that finding the `38.0` will be like finding the [_squeak_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_Than_a_Kite).

Comment: I'm just happy for an answer, it's been freaking me out all morning, rewrote that example from scratch half a dozen times wondering what stupid mistake I was making...