# How to use AffineTransform's translate?

Tags: java, swing, awt, affinetransform

I am not asking how AffineTransform works, but how to use its translate method.

I read the API many times, but still do not understand how it works.

> public void translate(double tx,double ty)
>
> Concatenates this transform with a translation transformation. This is equivalent to calling concatenate(T), where T is an AffineTransform represented by the following matrix:
>
> ```
>       [   1    0    tx  ]
>       [   0    1    ty  ]
>       [   0    0    1   ]
> ```

**Questions:**

1. affineTransform.translate(100, 0) somehow moves the image +100 pixel to the right and +100 pixel to the bottom. Why is this so?
2. Do I use translate() to move my images if I need to move my images very often? If not, what is the recommended method/ways to move my rotating/rotated images in a frame?

Comment: 1- Generally yes, it should move 100x and 0y, why its not would require a runnable example to determine. 2- this depends. Normally, I'd create a copy of the Graphics context before applying it or keeping a copy of the original, otherwise, you'll need to reverse it. Remember, any translations you apply are accumulative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> affineTransform.translate(100, 0) somehow moves the image +100 pixel to the right and +100 pixel to the bottom. Why is this so?

Generally speaking, yes, it should move the drawing offset to 100x and 0y, meaning that the `0x0` position of the `Graphics` context will now be `100x0` from the origin point of the original `Graphics` context.

Remember, translations are accumulative, this means that if you had previously translated the `Graphics` context in some way, this will now add to it (first translation `0x100`, second translation `100x0`, you are now `100x100` from the original `Graphics` contexts origin point...

> Do I use translate() to move my images if I need to move my images very often? If not, what is the recommended method/ways to move my rotating/rotated images in a frame?

Generally, I use `Graphics#create` to create a copy of the `Graphics` context (this copies the current state/properties, but will still generate output back to the original output of the `Graphics` context), apply the translations to the copy, paint whatever I want and then `dispose` of the copy.  This leaves the original context unchanged (in regards to the properties that I have changed)

This means you can do multiple translations in isolation which won't affect other translations performed later.

Another method would be to reverse the translations, but frankly, calling `dispose` on a copy is just simpler and easier...

Comment: Really appreciate your solution. However are you able to explain why is it shifting down and shifting right when I only supply 100 to `tx` ? https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/translation.html shows that by giving `tx` 100, the image should only shift right by 100 pixel. But why Java's translate is shifting it down as well?

Comment: Not unless you can give a runnable example. You might consider having a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507422/graphics-context-misaligned-on-first-paint) where I can issues with an initial transformation