# rotation of label while retrieving image from sql server in netbeans

Tags: swing

I am retrieving image from SQL server to net beans J-Frames on Label every time I retrieve image it is always shown 90 degree Clock wise rotated.I search a lot to rotate label so that image could be shown straight but I could not get any help .Kindly guide me how can I rotate label.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204114/rotating-an-image-object/30204975#30204975), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275424/rotating-image-with-affinetransform/20280225#20280225), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367149/how-to-use-affinetransform-quadrantrotate-to-rotate-a-bitmap/20368979#20368979), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824684/change-the-angle-position-of-a-drawing-with-a-algorithm-in-java/12826882#12826882)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/) class. It allows you to rotate the Icon however you want.

You just add the `RotatedIcon` to a JLabel like another other Icon and then add the label to the frame.